# Regex to Capture Text Between Rounded Bracket

Tags: regex

Im having trouble to create the regex pattern (javascript) to capture the text between rounded bracket. Hereby the string value:

```
var pattern = /->__\(([^)]+)\)/g;
var value = "Line 54:'label' => $this->helper('cms')->__('Images (%s)', implode(', ', $labels)),".match(pattern);
```

I need the output value as below

```
->__('Images (%s)', implode(', ', $labels))
```

Answer (score 1):

`var pattern = /->__.*\)\)/;` will work based on the fragment you posted, but I suspect that this question is really off-topic as it's a general javascript/regex question.

Comment: Apologize. Yeah, it had a bit complexity than just a simple matching.

Answer (score 1):

The only way I could see is to do two times regex as javascript don't support look behind regex.

```
var pattern = /__[^"]*/g;
var value = "Line 54:'label' => $this->helper('cms')->__('Images (%s)', implode(', ', $labels)),".match(pattern);
if(value.length){
    value = value[0].replace(/,$/,"");
}
```

Comment: Green, appreciate for your effort. I tried many patterns but to no avail. I'll keep trying, thanks anyway.